# Sort and Check whether the previous value is null in spotfire

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

I want to apply this logic in spotfire - If the current cell in InReworkFlag is null and previous cell is also null then it's 'REWORK'. I have to do this after sorting based on the date time column.

[image]

I tried using OVER and PREVIOUS functions but couldn't achieve the expected results. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Max([InReworkFlag]) OVER (Previous([StatusEndDateTime])